# Android Dagger 2 Injecting in Interceptor

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2, interceptor

I just got a problem to inject repository in the interceptor to get access token when its needed or rather expired. I just don't understand where I did something wrong. I just didn't find any example how to deal with interceptor and repository. Thinking about that double "Retrofit.Builder" maybe this is a problem. What do you think? And let's the code talk:

```
@Module
class AppModule {

@Singleton
@Provides
fun provideRefreshTokenService(client: OkHttpClient): RefreshTokenApi {
    return Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("https://id.twitch.tv/oauth2/")
        .client(client)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build()
        .create(RefreshTokenApi::class.java)
}

@Singleton
@Provides
fun provideHttpClient(headerInterceptor: HeaderInterceptor): OkHttpClient {
    return OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .addNetworkInterceptor(headerInterceptor)
        .build()
}

@Singleton
@Provides
fun provideRetrofit(client: OkHttpClient): TwichApi {
    return Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("https://api.igdb.com/v4/")
        .client(client)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build()
        .create(TwichApi::class.java)
}
}


    class TwichHeaderRepository @Inject constructor(
private val refreshTokenApi: RefreshTokenApi) 
 {
        suspend fun fetchRefreshToken(): Response<RefreshToken> {
            return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                refreshTokenApi.getRefreshToken()
            }
        }
    }


private const val TAG = "AddRepositoryAction"
private const val HEADER_CLIENT_ID = "Client-ID"
private const val HEADER_AUTHORIZATION = "Authorization"
private const val HEADER_ACCEPT = "Accept"
private const val DEFAULT_ACCESS_TOKEN = "mjycvndz4sasons2mg990kqme6vu6d"
private const val UNAUTHORIZED_STATUS_CODE = 401

@Singleton
class HeaderInterceptor @Inject constructor(
    private val context: Context,
    private val twichHeaderRepository: TwichHeaderRepository
) : Interceptor {

    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {

        val response = chain.proceed(chain.request().newBuilder().apply {
            header(HEADER_CLIENT_ID, "i3nzc6w3n0pod39zgsq8h445o2yp6p")
            header(HEADER_AUTHORIZATION, "Bearer $DEFAULT_ACCESS_TOKEN")
            header(HEADER_ACCEPT, "application/json")
        }.build())

        val refreshToken = runBlocking { generateAccessToken(twichHeaderRepository) }

        if (response.code == UNAUTHORIZED_STATUS_CODE) {
            response.close()
            val accessToken = ""
            return chain.proceed(chain.request().newBuilder().apply {
                header(HEADER_CLIENT_ID, "i3nzc6w3n0pod39zgsq8h445o2yp6p")
                header(HEADER_AUTHORIZATION, "Bearer $accessToken")
                header(HEADER_ACCEPT, "application/json")
            }.build())
        }
        return response
    }
}

private suspend fun generateAccessToken(twichHeaderRepository: TwichHeaderRepository): String 
{
    val responseRefreshToken = twichHeaderRepository.fetchRefreshToken()

    return responseRefreshToken.body().toString()
}


interface RefreshTokenApi {

    @POST(
       ...
    )
    suspend fun getRefreshToken(
    ): Response<RefreshToken>

}



@Singleton
@Component(modules = [AppModule::class])
interface AppComponent {

    @Component.Factory
    interface Factory {
        fun create(@BindsInstance context: Context): AppComponent
    }

    fun inject(activity: MainActivity)
    fun inject(fragment: AddFragment)
    fun inject(interceptor: HeaderInterceptor)
}



class TwichRepository @Inject constructor(
    private val twichApi: TwichApi
) {
    
    suspend fun searchGames(title: String): Response<Game> {
        return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) { twichApi.getGamesBySearch(title) }
    }
}
```

Error message is

```
Found a dependency cycle okhttp3.OkHttpClient is injected at
              com.example.glc.AppModule.provideRefreshTokenService(client)
          com.example.glc.add.RefreshTokenApi is injected at
              com.example.glc.add.TwichHeaderRepository(refreshTokenApi)
          com.example.glc.add.TwichHeaderRepository is injected at
              com.example.glc.add.HeaderInterceptor(�, twichHeaderRepository)
          com.example.glc.add.HeaderInterceptor is injected at
              com.example.glc.AppModule.provideHttpClient(headerInterceptor)
          okhttp3.OkHttpClient is injected at
              com.example.glc.AppModule.provideRetrofit(client)
          com.example.glc.add.TwichApi is injected at
              com.example.glc.add.TwichRepository(twichApi)
          com.example.glc.add.TwichRepository is injected at
              com.example.glc.add.AddViewModel(twichRepository)
          com.example.glc.add.AddViewModel is injected at
              com.example.glc.add.AddFragment.addViewModel
          com.example.glc.add.AddFragment is injected at
              com.example.glc.di.AppComponent.inject(com.example.glc.add.AddFragment)
```

Comment: " I just don't understand where I did something wrong" - Cyclic dependency error as stated in trace. Your `HeaderInterceptor` depends on `TwichHeaderRepository` depends on `RefreshTokenApi` depends on `Retrofit` depends on `OkHttpClient` depends on ... `HeaderInterceptor` - there cycle complete.  Use a way to refresh the token without cyclic dependency issues - possibly a different Okhttpclient instance that doesn't include your interceptor - this is easily done using `@Qualifier` or `@Named` annotations in Dagger.

Comment: HeaderInterceptor dependency on TwichHeaderRepository seems like a very strange design choice at first sight. Can you explain that design choice please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just needed to add `@Named` to resolve my problem and understand it as Mark said in the comment.

```
@Module
```

class AppModule {

```
@Singleton
@Provides
@Named("oauth2")
fun provideAccessTokenHttpClient() = OkHttpClient.Builder().build()

@Singleton
@Provides
fun provideRefreshTokenService(@Named("oauth2") client: OkHttpClient): RefreshTokenApi {
    return Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("https://id.twitch.tv/oauth2/")
        .client(client)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build()
        .create(RefreshTokenApi::class.java)
}

@Singleton
@Provides
@Named("igdb")
fun provideSearchDataHttpClient(headerInterceptor: HeaderInterceptor): OkHttpClient {
    return OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .addInterceptor(headerInterceptor)
        .build()
}

@Singleton
@Provides
fun provideRetrofit(@Named("igdb") client: OkHttpClient): TwichApi {
    return Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("https://api.igdb.com/v4/")
        .client(client)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build()
        .create(TwichApi::class.java)
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You use [`Lazy`](https://dagger.dev/api/latest/dagger/Lazy.html) on `TwichHeaderRepository` dependency in `HeaderInterceptor`'s constructor to break the dependency cycle.

```kotlin
class HeaderInterceptor @Inject constructor(
    private val lazyTwichHeaderRepository: Lazy<TwichHeaderRepository>
) {
    // Access the dependency lazily with lazyTwichHeaderRepository.get()
}
```